# Sitecore components sorted differently on master and web

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.2

When we do publish of a page after adding components to Sitecore via Experience Editor, the order of the component is different on the CD. So on the web database, when I go to presentation details for the page, all the components are sorted randomly, when it should be matching master.

How do I get the master components order to carry over to web?

Comment: Anything configured on the standard values of the template? or on the standard values of the base template? Are they the same in master and web database?

Comment: Nothing configured on the standard template and yes, both web and master are same for the templates.

Comment: It will be worth to re-build indexes and then do the full site publish.